# Calculate timezone difference in jquery

Tags: jquery, time, timezone, difference

I have two timezone js string variable.

```
var User_Timezone = new Date(); // current user system timezone
var User_Timezone= String(User_Timezone);

//User_Timezone has value = "Fri Feb 21 2014 04:29:49 GMT-07:00 (US Mountain Standard Time)";

var Admin_Timezone = "(GMT-06:00)-Central Time (US & Canada)"; //always same
```

I want to calculate time difference(**in minutes**) between `Admin Timezone` & `Client Timezone`.

**Like:**

```
var TimezoneDifference = Admin_Timezone - User_Timezone; // difference in minutes
```

How should I do this in **jQuery**?

Client timezone varies when any client access my page from different timezone but admin timezone is always same.

I need only difference between admin and client timezone.

Comment: `User_Timezone.getTimezoneOffset();  // get time zone offset in minutes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your server is always in GMT-6, or 360 minutes behind GMT, you can use **[`getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)** to get the client zone and subtract the latter from 360 to get the difference in minutes.

i.e.

```
var diff = 360 - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
```

**Note:** Change `360` if you relocate your server to another timezone.